# C++, Accessing String Characters in If-Else Statements (Beginner Question)

Tags: c++, string, character

I am new to c++ and had a question regarding something I came across.

My task is to read in a 3-character string from input into variable `passwordStr`, declare a boolean variable `containsDigit`, and set `containsDigit` to true if `passwordStr` contains a digit. Otherwise, set `containsDigit` to false.

What I currently have:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cctype>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    string passwordStr;
   
   bool containsDigit;
   
   getline(cin, passwordStr);
   
   if (isdigit(passwordStr.at(0 || 1 || 2))) {
      containsDigit = true;
   }
   
   if (containsDigit) {
      cout << "Valid password" << endl;
   }
   else {
      cout << "Invalid password" << endl;
   }

    return 0;
}
```

What is the logic and reasoning behind why `(isdigit(passwordStr.at(0 || 1 || 2)))` wouldn't work for what I'm intending to do?

I understand that something like `( isdigit(passwordStr.at(0)) || isdigit(passwordStr.at(1)) || isdigit(passwordStr.at(2)) )` would work instead, but I can't seem to understand how this is different than what I originally had.

Comment: If you look up the `isdigit()` function you must pass it 1 character not 3.  If you look up `std::string::at()` you must pass it 1 index not 3.

Comment: `0 || 1 || 2` is resolved immediately and will result in a boolean true or false. [Handy reading](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_logical). You need to do them separately and or the results.`isdigit(passwordStr.at(0)) || isdigit(passwordStr.at(1)) || isdigit(passwordStr.at(3))`

Comment: ^ yep, I was just adding that as point 2.  If you disable warnings you might even get `.at( 0 || 1 || 2)` to compile, but it will really be the boolean value  true (`.at(true)`) which could be promoted to int = 1 so `.at(1)`.    I haven't tried that with a modern compiler.  One more reason to enable warnings.

Comment: That makes much more sense, thank you guys so much for the info!

Answer (score 3):

As commenters have pointed out, in the expression:

```cpp
isdigit(passwordStr.at(0 || 1 || 2))
```

... the sub-expression `0 || 1 || 2` is evaluated first, and because this is a constant expression, you're effectively always calling:

```cpp
isdigit(passwordStr.at(true)) // true is converted to 1 in at()
```

We could do:

```cpp
bool containsDigit = isdigit(passwordStr.at(0)) ||
                     isdigit(passwordStr.at(1)) ||
                     isdigit(passwordStr.at(2));
```

... but this quickly gets out of hand when we want to test more indices.

Instead, we can use [`std::string::find_first_of`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/find_first_of):

```cpp
bool containsDigit = passwordStr.find_first_of("0123456789") != string::npos;
```

For larger character sets, `std::find_if` or `std::ranges::find_if` would also be suited.

##### Note

In general, you might want to avoid functions from `<cctype>`.
They:

- typically don't get inlined which makes them less efficient, and
- they return a nonzero/zero `int`, not a `bool`
- their behavior is undefined when passing a negative value other than `EOF` to them, which can easily happen when using `char`

Comment: You could also use [`std::any_of()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/all_any_none_of) instead, eg: `bool containsDigit = std::any_of(passwordStr.begin(), passwordStr.end(), [](unsigned char ch){return isdigit(ch)});` Or [`std::ranges::any_of()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/ranges/all_any_none_of)